# IntelliJ: use docker jvm or docker maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, docker, ide

I have a docker/jvm instance, which I use from the command line to compile and run java code. IntelliJ's project config requires me to point at a jvm on the filesystem.

So, I was wondering, can I configure intellij to use this docker container? I suppose I could configure a docker container, keep it running, and mount/share its filesystem, but I don't want that -- I want to use my ephemeral container instance.

I have the same idea for using maven -- can I use a docker instance of maven without mounting the filesystem, from within intellij? Again, intellij seems to require a pointer to a filesystem location for maven, so this seems problematic.

Does anyone have any clue if this is possible, or how to go about configuring such a thing?

Comment: May I know if you found a solution?  I am also using Java & Maven in Docker.  Could not find a way to configure IntelliJ to use the JDK :(

Comment: I moved to visual studio code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Again, intellij seems to require a pointer to a filesystem location for maven, so this seems problematic.

The only way for an application to use another *containerized* one would be for that application itself to be in the same container (or to mount a data volume from another container, which avoids mounting the local filesystem)

So using something like [`dlsniper/docker-intellij/`](https://hub.docker.com/r/dlsniper/docker-intellij/) (used for go, but easily adapted for java) would work, and allow an IntelliJ *container* to

- share the X11 socket in order to see the containerized application on the host desktop,
- uses **data volumes** (again, without mounting a local filesystem directly):

  - data-volume for the jvm
  - data-volume for the java sources

Comment: I'm trying to build a dev environment where the developer only has to install docker. I was also trying to utilise minimal resources to save power. It looks like, at the moment, the best I can do is follow the procedure outlined here, and talk to IntelliJ about the future (and the fact that its already here).

Comment: @EngineerDollery True. I would expect jetbrain itself to provide a ready-to-use IntelliJ IDEA as a docker image.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a posix system, you can make a simple executable shell script that takes command line argument and forwards those to:

```
docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARGS...]
```

This may even work on Windows with a batch file.

One problem is when you have to pass in file paths. A solution could be to mount the working directory at an identical path in the container, as on the host.

Don't forget the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) if you go for a shell script.

On Windows, a filepath may be 'unixified' in a batch file like this:

```
set FILEPATH=%FILEPATH:C:=/c%
set FILEPATH=%FILEPATH:\=/%
```

Comment: I've tried this -- it still needs the host to have java (and maven) installed, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I want my developers to only install docker so that I can have a single definition of a dev environment and a single upgrade point. Good answer though, so +1